# How can I disable the YouTube share button in my React Native app?

Tags: react-native

Currently, I am using the React Native YouTube iframe library which does not allow this.i tried other libraries but nothing seem to work .

i also tried other ways to embedd in webview but the problem persist. i just cant get rid of share functionality